# Взять элемент со страницы через ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Написал небольшой скрипт корзины, вывожу купленный товар на странице корзины, вывожу товар так: Посылаю ajax запрос на страницу товара и пытаюсь от туда вытащить id="productName".
скрипт корзины выглядит примерно так:

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                var limkForProductPage = '/e-store/' + localStorage.key(i);//ссылка на страницу товара
                    $( "#rezult" ).load( "limkForProductPage #productName" );

            }
```

Но проблема в том что jquery не понимаю что limkForProductPage это переменная и пытается перейти по адресу mysite.com/limkForProductPage 
Пробовал на на нативном js но не понимаю как мне взять нужный элемент например

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', p, false);
            xhr.send();
            if (xhr.status != 200) {
            alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); 
            } else {
            // вывести результат
            var xmlDoc = xhr.responseText;       
            }
```

а как мне взять id="productName"? пробовал так

```
   var xmlDoc = xhr.responseText.getElementById('productName');
```

но выдает ошибку

Comment: очевидно ошибка в том, что у строки **нет** метода  `getElementById`

Comment: Переменную limkForProductPage  из кавычек вынесите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ES2015 можно использовать [шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

```
$("#rezult").load(`${limkForProductPage} #productName`);
```

Либо просто собрать строку

```
$("#rezult").load(limkForProductPage + " #productName");
```

---

В случае с `XMLHttpRequest` - можно попробовать использовать свойство [responseXML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/XMLHttpRequest#responseXML), у которого уже есть `getElementById`

Либо перевести содержимое `responseText` в HTML, и уже затем  производить поиск.

---

В качестве решения проблемы загрузки нескольких элементов в один, можно загружать данные для разных url, в разные элементы, которые потом вставлять в основной элемент `#result`, например так

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var limkForProductPage = '/e-store/' + localStorage.key(i);//ссылка на страницу товара
    $( "#rezult" ).append(
        $('<div></div>').load( limkForProductPage + " #productName" )
    );
}
```

Comment: смотрите какая проблема всплыла при использовании $("#rezult").load(limkForProductPage + " #productName"); - в #rezult записывается последнее значение цикла т.е. если в корзине три товара и цикло for отработает три раза в #rezult попадет последнее значение, это  можно как то поправить?

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов, и это вполне логично, вы в один и тот же контейнер пхаете разные данные. какие придут последними. те и покажутся

Comment: Спасибо! Не большая правка
`$( "#rezult" ).append(
            $('<div></div>').load( limkForProductPage + " #productName" )
         );`

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов, поправил, вот поэтому копирование - плохо :)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй сделать так:

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  var limkForProductPage = '/e-store/' + localStorage.key(i); //ссылка на страницу товара
  $.get(limkForProductPage).done(function(responce){
    var document=$(responce);
    var element = document.find("#productName");
    $( "#rezult" ).append(element);
  });
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?