# Уникальность id в HTML

Tags: html

Вопрос на странице может быть только один такой id вообще или один id именно у этого тега. Корректно ли делать?

```
<div id="1">
    <p id="1"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Один на странице. Цитата: "В коде **документа** каждый идентификатор уникален и должен быть включён лишь один раз."  http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/identifikatory-i-klassy

Comment: и цифрой быть он не может. начинаться должен с латинского символа

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich ну это спорно ;)

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich, уже может, начиная с html5

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я 100% отвечал уже на подобный вопрос про уникальность, но найти не могу :(

Comment: @Grundy тебе надо вести табель учёта ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да тут поиск плохо работает прост!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский / Grundy Ничёсе.. Ок. Будем знать ) хотя:  [тык](https://jsfiddle.net/ydg5qck4/)

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich ага. будем знать https://jsfiddle.net/03f24wv2/

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich, это потому что ты неправильно используешь. Ну и [немножко спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Количество одинаковых id может быть **любым**. Страница от этого не свалится с ошибками, а операционная система не покажет синее окно смерти.

Но почему так делать не стоит:

1. Семантика. Id подразумевает свою уникальность. Когда вы пишете `span id="mySpan"` вы **обещаете** всем, кто читает вашу страницу, что больше таких id не будет.
2. Выборка. `getElementById`, `$('#selector')` вернет вам **первый** встреченный элемент и проигнорирует все остальные. Т.е. если у вас их несколько на странице, шанс случайно ошибки значительно возрастает.
3. Применение стилей. В случае с несколькими одинаковыми id применение стилей будет не однозначно. Кто-то применит их ко всем id, кто-то к первому, кто-то к последнему. Кстати, поведение в п. 2 тоже не гарантировано.
4. HTML валидаторы. В некоторых командах используются HTML валидаторы. Они просто не пропустят ваш код.

Comment: в пункт про выборку стоит добавить про применение стилей

Comment: Спасибо. Только вопрос: если у меня id в переменной, то как использовать выбор по селектору?
`var sel = 'selector';`
как теперь сделать `$('#sel')` ?

Comment: @fosh4455 `$(sel)`. но это уже никак не относится к тому вопросу, что ты задал. Если интересен другой вопрос - задай еще один)

Comment: @fosh4455, [например так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513884/186999)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский вы тут модератор?

Comment: @fosh4455 правила таковы, что если возникают какие-то новые вопросы по новой проблеме/теме/ - вы их задаете. Комментарии предназначены для уточнений по текущему вопросу/ответу. Если вы не готовы принимать правила ресурса - то вам стоит поискать другой, подходящий под ваши желания

Comment: @Grundy а вот тут уже я не в курсе похоже. Стили тоже применятся к первому элементу?

Comment: @Vitalii, на самом деле - это не тривиальный вопрос :-) все на усмотрение браузера и то как он будет разбирать дерево

Comment: @Grundy  Т.е. мы имеем неопределенное поведение для стилей. Ясно, спасибо.

Comment: @Vitalii. я бы сказал, что к одному элементу стили точно применятся, но к какому мы не можем гарантировать

Comment: Исправил и спасибо за уточнение.

Comment: @Vitalii стиль применяется ко всех элементам с одинаковым ID. :)

Comment: Я тоже так думал но вот тут @Grundy говорит что это не гарантировано. И я действительно нигде не видел обещание такого поведения.

Comment: @Grundy https://jsfiddle.net/h791qpLf/1/  - объясните пожалуйста)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский я не Grundy но речь идет о том, что это не гарантированное поведение. Т.е. если у нас есть div то мы знаем, что он займет всю ширину родителя и так **должны** вести себя все браузеры, так как это стандарт. В случае с перекрывающимися id браузеры вольны вести себя так как хотят и мы можем только надеться что они поведут себя так и будут вести так и дальше.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, забавно, в [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#id-selectors) описан только случай когда у одного элемента несколько id. В остальном указано _ID typed attribute can be used to uniquely identify its element._ Так что, результат вполне может быть своеволием браузеров :)

Comment: @Grundy всех сжечь!)

Answer (score 6):

Атрибут id - уникальное имя элемента, которое используется для изменения его стиля и обращения к нему через скрипты. Идентификатор в коде документа должен быть в единственном экземпляре, иными словами, встречаться только один раз.

Пример:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Атрибут id</title>
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div id="help">
   <p>За помощью можно обратится в stackoverflow.</p>
  </div>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: В ваших правках есть однотипная ошибка: вы, как и многие новички считаете, что много форматирования -- это хорошо. Почитайте эту тему на мете про форматирование http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/ особенно про внутристрочное форматирование